# Rails app login fails with certain browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser, authentication

I recently made a rails app using Michael Hartl's tutorial, but I hit a snag;

whenever someone creates a user using chrome or firefox, it creates the user and logs in; as it should. But when the user is created using safari or IE, the user is created but the login fails. The user can, however, then be logged into using chrome or firefox. I suspect this has something to do with cookies and sessions, but I don't know what I should do to fix this.

Here's the site: http://www.shoulakpredictions.com
Here's the code: https://github.com/JShoe/basketball

Feel free to fork and test and create users and whatnot. I need all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the browser has cookies enabled, from all sources. With Chrome and Firefox, that is the default setting, but with other browsers, it might have to be specifically enabled.